# Custom JPanel class does not show up in BoxLayout of Container

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

Selected code from SCMain.java:

```
public JPanel createContentPane() {
    //Create the content-pane-to-be.
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);

    return contentPane;
}

public JPanel populateContentPane() {
    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    JPanel panel1 = new AddAccountForm(this, this.getInputSet());;
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

    container.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
    container.add(panel1);
    container.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
    container.add(panel2);
    container.add(Box.createGlue());
    return container;
}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sole Commando v1.0");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    frame.setJMenuBar(this.createMenuBar());
    frame.setContentPane(this.createContentPane());

    // Add split panels
    frame.add(populateContentPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.pack();
    //Display the window.
    frame.setSize(1080, 1080);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Selected code from AddAccountForm.java:

```
public class AddAccountForm extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    AddAccountForm(SCMain main, Set<String> InputSet) {
        //Combobox setup

        setSize(300, 300);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(storeNameList.toArray()));
        submitButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public JPanel getAddAccountRoot() {
        return addAccountRoot;
    }

    private void createUIComponents() {
        // TODO: place custom component creation code here
        storeNames = new JComboBox();
    }
}
```

I tested using the AddAccountForm.java as a JFrame (extend JFrame instead of extend JPanel, and adding pack(), setContentPane(addAccountRoot) to AddAccountForm.java) and it brought up the correct AddAccountForm GUI if I just did:

```
SCMain new1 = new SCMain();
AddAccountForm new2 = new AddAccountForm(new1, new1.getInputSet());
```

However, when using it as a JPanel (panel1 in the above SCMain.java code) and running SCMain, AddAccountForm GUI does not show up at all.
Note: The JPanel AddAccountForm was created in IntelliJ GUI Builder, but as I said previously it works as a JFrame so the code must be somewhat correct.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).